# Create Virtual Directory in Service Definition File using Azure Storage

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-blob-storage

I was wondering if it was possible to set the Physical Path of a virtual directory in a service definition file to azure storage (blob etc).

```
<VirtualDirectory name="Content" physicalDirectory="{azure storage}" />
```

Currently i have some image content that i have have in blob storage which i would like to be accessed via the virtual directory.

Is this possible? Any examples would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, it is not possible to map a virtual directory to blob storage. Instead, you could map a custom domain to your blob storage. For example, you could map `youraccount.blob.core.windows.net` to something like `staticcontent.yourwebsite.com` and then serve images from a container using `staticcontent.yourwebsite.com/images/logo.png`.

Please see this link for more details: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/storage-custom-domain-name/.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible to create a virtual directory pointing to blob storage.

However, if the blob storage container is publicly readable then you could create a reverse proxy to have the same effect.

You can find instructions on setting up reverse proxy here: http://ruslany.net/2014/05/using-azure-web-site-as-a-reverse-proxy/